# How to make selenium threads run (each thread with its own driver)

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, selenium

I have a python 3 script that needs to make thousands of requests to multiple different websites and check if their source code pass in some pre defined rules.

I am using selenium to make the requests because I need to get the source code after JS finishes it excecution, but due to the high number of urls I need to check, I am trying to make it run multiple threads simultaneously. Each thread creates and maintain an instance of webdriver to make the requests. The problem is after a while all threads go silent and simply stop executing, leaving just a single thread doing all the work. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
def get_browser(use_firefox = True):
    if use_firefox:
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        options.headless = True
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)
        browser.implicitly_wait(4)
        return browser
    else:
        chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        browser.implicitly_wait(4)
        return browser

def start_validations(urls, rules, results, thread_id):
    try:
        log("thread %s started" % thread_id, thread_id)
        browser = get_browser(thread_id % 2 == 1)
        while not urls.empty():
            url = "http://%s" % urls.get()
            try:
                log("starting %s" % url, thread_id)
                browser.get(url)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                WebDriverWait(browser, 6).until(selenium_wait_reload(4))
                html = browser.page_source
                result = check_url(html, rules)

                original_domain = url.split("://")[1].split("/")[0].replace("www.","")
                tested_domain = browser.current_url.split("://")[1].split("/")[0].replace("www.","")
                redirected_url = "" if tested_domain == original_domain else browser.current_url

                results.append({"Category":result, "URL":url, "Redirected":redirected_url})
                log("finished %s" % url, thread_id)
            except Exception as e:
                log("couldn't test url %s" % url, thread_id )
                log(str(e), thread_id)
                results.append({"Category":"Connection Error", "URL":url, "Redirected":""})
                browser.quit()
                time.sleep(2)
                browser = get_browser(thread_id % 2 == 1)
    except Exception as e:
        log(str(e), thread_id)
    finally:
        log("closing thread", thread_id)
        browser.quit()

def calculate_progress(urls):
    progress_folder ="%sprogress/" % WEBROOT
    if not os.path.exists(progress_folder):
        os.makedirs(progress_folder)

    initial_size = urls.qsize()
    while not urls.empty():
        current_size = urls.qsize()
        on_queue = initial_size - current_size
        progress = '{0:.0f}'.format((on_queue / initial_size * 100))
        for progress_file in os.listdir(progress_folder):
            file_path = os.path.join(progress_folder, progress_file)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path) and not file_path.endswith(".csv"):
                os.unlink(file_path)
        os.mknod("%s%s" % (progress_folder, progress))
        time.sleep(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            log("scraper started")
            if os.path.isfile(OUTPUT_FILE):
                os.unlink(OUTPUT_FILE)

            manager = Manager()

            rules = fetch_rules()
            urls = manager.Queue()
            fetch_urls()
            results = manager.list()

            jobs = []
            p = Process(target=calculate_progress, args=(urls,))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
            for i in range(THREAD_POOL_SIZE):
                log("spawning thread with id %s" % i)
                p = Process(target=start_validations, args=(urls, rules, results, i))
                jobs.append(p)
                p.start()
                time.sleep(2)
            for j in jobs:
                j.join()

            save_results(results, OUTPUT_FILE)
            log("scraper finished")
        except Exception as e:
            log(str(e))
```

As you can see, first I thought I could only have one instance of the browser, so I tried to run at least firefox and chrome in paralel, but this still leaves only a thread to do all the work.

Some times the driver crahsed and the thread stopped working even though it is inside a try/catch block, so I started to get a new instance of the browser everytime this happens,but it still didn't work. I also tried waiting a few seconds between creating each instance of the driver still with no results

here is a pastebin of one of the log files:

https://pastebin.com/TsjZdRYf

A strange thing that I noticed is that almost everytime the only thread that keeps running is the last one spawned (with id 3).

Thanks for your time and you help!

EDIT:

[1] Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/fvVPwPVb

[2] custom selenium wait condition: https://pastebin.com/Zi7nbNFk

Comment: Looks like you're manipulating the URLs. Do you have to use Selenium? I'm asking because they open up the browser and this consumes a lot of memory and other overhead. Can you use requests library instead?

Comment: yes, unfortunately I have to... My first attempt was just using requests, but I need to get the source code after the JS in the page finishes manipulating the DOM (i.e. making ajax requests to show something, or to redirect to another page)

Comment: You can allow the redirects in the requests library. It's also possible to make ajax requests. [Click!](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

Comment: yeah, it is possible if I know what requests are being made. There are also websites that test if JS is enabled and then serve you a different page if JS is disabled. But if you can share a snippet to replicate the requests that thousands of different websites make I'll gladly go with that solution xD

Comment: Can you host your full code somewhere that we can see? I'd like to get my hands dirty with it

Comment: sure, just updated the question. If you have any solutions please post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Am I allowed to curse on SO? I solved the problem, and I don't think this answer should exist on SO because nobody else will benefit from it. The problem was a custom wait condition that I had created. This class is in the pastebin that was added in edit 2, but I'll also add it here for convenince:

```
import time
class selenium_wait_reload:
    def __init__(self, desired_repeating_sources):
        self.desired_repeating_sources = desired_repeating_sources
        self.repeated_pages = 0
        self.previous_source = None

    def __call__(self, driver):
        while True:
            current_source = driver.page_source
            if current_source == self.previous_source:
                self.repeated_pages = self.repeated_pages +1
                if self.repeated_pages >= self.desired_repeating_sources:
                    return True
            else:
                self.previous_source = current_source
                self.repeated_pages = 0
            time.sleep(0.3)
```

The goal of this class was to make selenium wait because the JS could be loading additional DOM.

So, this class makes selenium wait a short time and check the code, wait a little again and check the code again. The class repeats this until the source code is the same 3 times in a row.

The problem is that there are some pages that have a js carrousel, so the source code is never the same. I thought that in cases like this the WebDriverWait second parameter would make it crash with a timeoutexception. I was wrong.

Comment: use WebDriverWait

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg do you have a suggestion of an expected condition? for all that I have researched people said that it is not a trivial task, and everything I tried (including rolling my own custom wait condition) failed, so I just decided to wait for a fixed X seconds...

Comment: your answer is totally unrelated to the question asked

Comment: No it is not, perhaps you misunderstood something. The question basically asks: "Why is this script not running all its threads until the end?" The answer is "Because the threads are running a code that makes it wait forever. This code is the class in the answer"

Comment: your solution is a fix to code that wasn't in the question.